# Questions & Answers module/app for Sharepoint 365

Tags: sharepoint-online

is there a way to have stackoverlow-like module at Sharepoint 365?
With voting for answers and choosing the best one.

I know there were questions like this already, but for older versions, long time ago.

Comment: Not OOTB but trough third-party products

Comment: I see, whould you recommend any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the OOB Discussion board in SharePoint Online.

Or you can activate the **Community Site Feature** via `Site settings > Manage site features` to get a full function of Discussion feature.

[image]

You can create categories, start discussions, like/vote for replies and set best reply for the discussion. It’s not exactly stackoverlow-like but it covers most functions you need for a community.

[image]

Reference:
[Join a discussion.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/join-a-discussion-3431a5d5-48da-425b-9626-af04b48b075b)